# Left recursion, associativity and AST evaluation

Tags: parsing, recursion, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree

So I have been reading a bit on lexers, parser, interpreters and even compiling.

For a language I'm trying to implement I settled on a Recrusive Descent Parser. Since the original grammar of the language had left-recursion, I had to slightly rewrite it.

Here's a simplified version of the grammar I had (note that it's not any standard format grammar, but somewhat pseudo, I guess, it's how I found it in the documentation):

```
expr:
-----
expr + expr
expr - expr
expr * expr
expr / expr
( expr )
integer
identifier
```

To get rid of the left-recursion, I turned it into this (note the addition of the NOT operator):

```
expr:
-----
expr_term {+ expr}
expr_term {- expr}
expr_term {* expr}
expr_term {/ expr}

expr_term:
----------
! expr_term
( expr )
integer
identifier
```

And then go through my tokens using the following sub-routines (simplified pseudo-code-ish):

```
public string Expression()
{
    string term = ExpressionTerm();

    if (term != null)
    {
        while (PeekToken() == OperatorToken)
        {
            term += ReadToken() + Expression();
        }
    }

    return term;
}

public string ExpressionTerm()
{
    //PeekToken and ReadToken accordingly, otherwise return null
}
```

This works! The result after calling `Expression` is always equal to the input it was given.

This makes me wonder: If I would create AST nodes rather than a string in these subroutines, and evaluate the AST using an infix evaluator (which also keeps in mind associativity and precedence of operators, etcetera), won't I get the same result?

And if I do, then why are there so many topics covering "fixing left recursion, keeping in mind associativity and what not" when it's actually "dead simple" to solve or even a non-problem as it seems? Or is it really the structure of the resulting AST people are concerned about (rather than what it evaluates to)? Could anyone shed a light, I might be getting it all wrong as well, haha!

Comment: The purpose of a parser is to produce an interpretation (actions), or a translation (an equivalent document in the same or another language, like in optimization, annotation, or compilation). Reproducing the original input is uninteresting.

Comment: I assumed it showed I got my recursion loop right in that if I would change the string to a node-tree instead, I'd also end up with a grammatically correct "sentence". Is this assumption incorrect?

Comment: Reproducing the input proves nothing about recognizing the structure. It can be done by echoing, or by luck. A simple and revealing translation to try would be to convert the input to prefix or postfix (Polish) notation. You could even build an evaluator for postfix to know if you're interpreting the input structure correctly. In your case, you'll find that you're not, because all operators are at the same level. You would need some kind of operator precedence tho grok that a+b*3 means a+(b*3) and not (a+b)*3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shape of the AST *is* important, since `a+(b*3)` is not usually the same as `(a+b)*3` and one might reasonably expect the parser to indicate which of those `a+b*3` means.

Normally, the AST will actually delete parentheses. (A parse tree wouldn't, but an AST is expected to abstract away syntactic noise.) So the AST for `a+(b*3)` should look something like:

```
          Sum
           |
       +---+---+
       |       |
      Var     Prod
       |       |
       a   +---+---+
           |       |
          Var    Const
           |       |
           b       3
```

If you language obeys usual mathematical notation conventions, so will the AST for `a+b*3`.

An "infix evaluator" -- or what I imagine you're referring to -- is just another parser. So, yes, if you are happy to parse later, you don't have to parse now.

By the way, showing that you can put tokens back together in the order that you read them doesn't actually demonstrate much about the parser functioning. You could do that much more simply by just echoing the tokenizer's output.

Comment: Ahhh, I'm starting to get it now, so an AST is pretty much 'evaluation ready', as in, you just go through it not actually having to parse any more (which would still be the case for a parse tree)?

Comment: Evaluation ready as in, expressions like these are stored postfix in the AST (for example). Maybe I'm overcomplicating the thought process though.

Comment: @LennardFonteijn: A parse tree is also ready to evaluate. You just have to ignore more stuff. (Eg. eval of the `( expr )` rule consists of "return the value of the second child"). Trees are usually stored as trees, so postfix and prefix are not relevant. (Or, if you prefer, they're class methods, since a tree can be traversed preorder or postorder.)

Answer (score 0):

The standard and easiest way to deal with expressions, mathematical or other, is with a rule hierarchy that reflects the intended associations and operator precedence:

```
expre = sum

sum = addend '+' sum | addend

addend = term '*' addend | term

term = '(' expre ')' | '-' integer | '+' integer | integer
```

Such grammars let the parse or abstract trees be directly evaluatable. You can expand the rule hierarchy to include power and bitwise operators, or make it part of the hierarchy for logical expressions with `and` `or` and comparisons.

Comment: I have experimented with this and while this works, you have to go through a `n` number of precedence levels before you get to your terms, not too mention the maintainability is awful. I have now developed an algorithm which builds the tree accordingly, I'm not sure if it exists under a well-known name yet, but I'll post it later today.

Comment: Apparently I came up with a derivation of Precedence Climbing: http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/Misc/exp_parsing.htm#climbing